# How to extract dependency of concrete type?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory, abstract-factory

I have a requirement where the the user needs to configure how they would like to get alerted when an error happens.  The options they have are the following:

1.) Create an event in the event log

2.) Send an email to an email specified from the user interface

The classes i am using currently use the following interface

```
interface INotificationSender
{
   virtual void SendMessage(string message);
}
```

my interface is going to be implemented by the following 2 concrete classes

```
class EmailerNotificationSender: public INotificationSender
{
   string m_EmailAddress;

   public EmailerNotificationSender(string emailAddress)
   {
       m_EmailAddress = emailAddress;
   }
   public virtual void SendMessage(string Message)
   {
      // Send Message to email specified in member variable
   }
} 


class EventLogNotificationSender: public INotificationSender
{
   public virtual void SendMessage(string Message)
   {
      // Log message in event log using
   }

}
```

My current interface code looks like the following

```
public class MyUserinterfaceWindow
{
    private INotificationSender m_NotificationSender; // concrete type depends on user interface selection!

    public void Button_Click(...)
    {
       if (emailSelected)
       {
           m_NotificationSender = new EmailerNotificationSender(textbox.email)
           return;
       }
        m_NotificationSender = new EventLogNotificationSender();
    }

    public void SendAlert()
    {
        m_NotificationSender.SendMessaged("SOMETHING BAD HAPPENED");
    }
}
```

**Summary/Question:**
How do i remove the presence of concrete types being instantiated( for example EventLogNotificationSender and EmailerNotificationSender )

**NOTE:** EventLogNotificationSender requires no parameters in it's concrete constructor while EmailNotificationSender's concrete constructor takes a string parameter!

Comment: Why would your alert configuration window have a `SendAlert()` method ? If you stored user preferences somewhere instead of having a hardwired `m_NotificationSender` in your window, you could then instantiate `NotificationSenders` on the fly when needed based on configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the two implementations behind a [composite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) `INotificationSender` implementation.

If you can to delay the user's choice to which source he wants to log, you can move that selection logic into the composite and this prevents this logic from cluttering the `MyUserinterfaceWindow`. Here's an example:

```cs
public class CompositeNotificationSender : INotificationSender {
    private readonly EmailerNotificationSender mailer;
    private readonly EventLogNotificationSender eventLogger;

    public CompositeNotificationSender(
        EmailerNotificationSender mailer,
        EventLogNotificationSender eventLogger) {
        this.mailer = mailer;
        this.eventLogger = eventLogger;
    }

    public virtual void SendMessage(string Message) {
        bool logToMail = AskUserWhereToLog();
        var logger = logToMail ? this.mailer : this.eventLogger;
        logger.SendMessage(Message);
    }

    private bool AskUserWhereToLog() {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Since this class asks the user, there is a dependency with the UI and this class is UI specific. If that's not an option, this could be extracted as well. And of course you could prevent having to ask the user more than once by caching the result if you wish.

If asking the user just-in-time doesn't work, you can create an abstraction that both the `CompositeNotificationSender` and `MyUserinterfaceWindow` can depend on that can hold the user's preference:

```cs
public interface IUserLoggingPreference
{
    bool LogToMail { get; set; }
}
```

The `MyUserinterfaceWindow` (or any other place) can now depend on `IUserLoggingPreference` and change the `LogToMail` value to change the user's preference. The `CompositeNotificationSender` will look like this:

```cs
public class CompositeNotificationSender : INotificationSender {
    private readonly IUserLoggingPreference preference;
    private readonly EmailerNotificationSender mailer;
    private readonly EventLogNotificationSender eventLogger;

    public CompositeNotificationSender(
        IUserLoggingPreference preference,
        EmailerNotificationSender mailer,
        EventLogNotificationSender eventLogger) {
        this.preference = preference;
        this.mailer = mailer;
        this.eventLogger = eventLogger;
    }

    public virtual void SendMessage(string Message) {
        var logger = this.preference.LogToMail ? this.mailer : this.eventLogger;
        logger.SendMessage(Message);
    }
}
```

This way the user doesn't have to be prompted after he clicks the button and the `CompositeNotificationSender` is independent on the user interface, which makes it easier to reuse this logic (for instance in a part of the system where there is no user interaction) and it makes it easier to unit test this class.